# Appium gives 'Error: Intent matches multiple activities while running test

Tags: ruby, android-intent, cucumber, appium, appium-android

I am running test in android device (Samsung S10+) with `ruby 2.5.3` with `cucumber 5.1.2` and `'appium_lib', '~>10.6.0'`. While running test I see that appium server sent command to mobile device to unlock mobile but after sometime I get `unknown server-side error` not sure what it is and I couldn't find any help on google, I am able to start the app manually by using below adb command `adb shell am start -W -n com.login.mobile.MainActivity -S -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -f 0x10200000` but when I run the test it gives error.

Logs

`W3C] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Cannot start the 'com.login.mobile' application. Visit https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md for troubleshooting. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command '/Users/dk/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s R58MA7HJXZL shell am start -W -S -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -f 0x10200000' exited with code 1'; Stderr: 'Error: Intent matches multiple activities; can't stop: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 }'; Code: '1' [W3C]     at ADB.startApp (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-adb/lib/tools/apk-utils.js:177:11)`

caps

```
ef caps
  {
    caps:{
      deviceName: "Galaxy S10+",
      platformName: "Android",
      #app: "#{Dir.pwd}/features/resources/app/app-release.apk",
      appPackage: "com.login.mobile",
      appAcitivity: "com.login.mobile.MainActivity",
      skipServerInstallation: true,
      newCommandTimeout: "60000",
      autoacceptalerts: true,
      autoGrantPermissions: true,
      clearSystemFiles: true
    }
  }
```

Comment: I face the same issue any advise on how this was fixed? I did not misspell Activity.

Comment: can you copy past your caps?

Comment: {
  "UDID": "emulator-5554",
  "platformName": "Android",
  "deviceName": "Pixel 3 API 29 V10",
  "platformVersion": "10",
  "appPackage": "com.mcm.app",
  "appActivity": "com.mcm.app.LaunchActivity"
}

Comment: @user1622681 it is working fine, this is my android json file:
{"caps": {"UDID": "emulator-5554","deviceName": "emulator","platformName": "Android","app": "#{Dir.pwd}/features/resources/app/app-release.apk","appPackage": "com.login.mobile.MainActivity","appActivity": "MainActivity","skipServerInstallation": true,"newCommandTimeout": "60000","autoacceptalerts": true,"autoGrantPermissions": true,"clearSystemFiles": true},"appium_lib_options": {"server_url": "http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"}}

Comment: this is how I use it

 
cap = File.read("./features/resources/android_device.json")
options = eval(cap)
$driver = Appium::Driver.new(options, false)

Comment: check your appPackage and appActivity, I think this could be a problem if you gives incorrect package and activity

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem, it is due to typo in `appAcitivity` correcting typo has fix the issue